# postgtresql parameters multiple types

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to define a PostgreSQL function that can accept multiple types for the same parameter? For example, given the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (
    bar INTEGER
)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
    ...
```

Is there some kind of way to change `bar` to also allow array types, kind of like this (but I know this does not work):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (
    bar INTEGER OR INTEGER[]
)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the polymorphic type `anyelement` and the function `pg_typeof()`, e.g.:

```
create or replace function test(anyelement)
returns text language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if pg_typeof($1) = 'integer'::regtype then
        return format ('integer: %s', $1);
    elsif pg_typeof($1) = 'integer[]'::regtype then
        return format ('int array: %s', $1);
    else
        return format ('other: %s', $1);
    end if;
end $$;

select test(1), test(array[1,2]), test('text'::text);

    test    |       test       |    test     
------------+------------------+-------------
 integer: 1 | int array: {1,2} | other: text
(1 row)
```

Note that the function cannot resolve argument's type when it is a string literal (as opposed to functions with arguments of regular types), e.g.

```
select test('1');

ERROR:  could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown
```

In typical cases two overloaded functions will be a better approach. Polymorphic types have their limitations.

Read more about:

- [polymorphic types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC)
- [overloaded functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-overload.html)

Answer (score -1):

no, you have to create two functions with same name for it:

```
t=# create or replace function fi(a int) returns text as $$
begin
return a;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# create or replace function fi(a int[]) returns text as $$
begin
return a;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select fi(3);
 fi
----
 3
(1 row)
t=# select fi('{3,4}'::int[]);
  fi
-------
 {3,4}
(1 row)
```